# Bloch sphere rotation axis determined phase of light?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, radiation, rotation, bloch-sphere

From what I have derived and read (see e.g. pg 13 of the pdf linked to [here](https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/90582)) the phase $\varphi$ of the radiation incident on a two-level system determines the axis of rotation. In such a case the time variation of the probability amplitudes $c_1$ and $c_2$ of the two levels in the rotating wave approximation are:
$$\newcommand{\p}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} \newcommand{\f}[2]{\frac{ #1}{ #2}} \newcommand{\l}[0]{\left(} \newcommand{\r}[0]{\right)} \newcommand{\mean}[1]{\langle #1 \rangle}\newcommand{\e}[0]{\varepsilon}\dot c_1=-\f{1}{2}ic_2 e^{i\varphi}$$
$$\dot c_2=-\f{1}{2}i c_2 e^{-i\varphi}$$
My question is: in the case I have just described what is the phase $\varphi$ with respect to, why can't we get rid of it with a redefinition of the time origin and how can it lead to a change in the rotation axis in the Bloch sphere when it appears arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

As you've written it, it is twice the phase between the two time derivatives. So it's a phase relationship between constituents of a quantum superposition - it's not a common phase - and so it cannot be removed by a change of time origin. I suspect that one of the signs in your two equations is wrong and that the $2\times1$ vector of superposition weights is meant to be:

$$\exp\left(i\,\sigma_z\,\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\,\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right)\,c_2\tag{1}$$

where $\sigma_z$ is the diagonal Pauli matrix and then the time derivative of this $2\times1$ quantity would be as you've written when $\varphi$ increases by one radian per unit time.

If this is a polarization state of light, then it represents the evolution of a linear polarization state input at $45^\circ$ to the principal axes of a birefringent crystal and the state above in (1) is the state after it has propagated some distance, and the delay between the p and s components is $\varphi$.